# How to increase scheduler memory in GKE for DASK

Tags: python, google-kubernetes-engine, dask, prefect, mlops

I have deployed a kubernetes cluster on GCP with a combination of prefect and dask. The jobs run fine in a normal scenario but it is failing to scale for 2 times the data. So far, I have narrowed it down to scheduler getting shut off due to high memory usage.
[Dask scheduler Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdOS4.png)
As soon as the memory usage touches 2GB, the jobs get failed up with "no heartbeat detected" error.

There is a separate build python file available where we set worker memory and cpu. There is a dask-gateway package where we get the Gateway options and set up the worker memory.

```
options.worker_memory = 32
options.worker_cores = 10
cluster = gateway.new_cluster(options)
cluster.adapt(minimum=4, maximum=20)
```

I am unable to figure out where and how can i increase the memory allocation for dask-scheduler.

```
Specs:
Cluster Version: 1.19.14-gke.1900
Machine type - n1-highmem-64
Autoscaling set to 6 - 1000 nodes per zone
all nodes are allocated 63.77 CPU and 423.26 GB
```

Answer (score 5):

To explain why Flow heartbeats exist in the first place:
Prefect uses heartbeats to check if your flow is still running. If Prefect didn’t have heartbeats, flows that lost communication and died on a remote execution environment such as a Kubernetes job, would permanently be shown as Running in the UI. Usually "no heartbeat detected" happens as a result of running out of memory, or when your flows execute long-running jobs.

One solution that you could try is to set the following environment variable on your run configuration - this will change the heartbeats behavior from processes to threads and can help solve the issue:

```py
from prefect.run_configs import UniversalRun

flow.run_config = UniversalRun(env={"PREFECT__CLOUD__HEARTBEAT_MODE": "thread"})
```

As you mentioned, the best solution would be to increase the memory of your Dask workers. If you use a long-running cluster, you can set it this way:

```
dask-worker tcp://scheduler:port --memory-limit="4 GiB"
```

And if you pass a cluster class to your Dask executor, e.g. `coiled.Cluster`, you can set both:

- scheduler_memory - defaults to 4 GiB
- worker_memory - defaults to 8 GiB

Here is how you could set that on your flow:

```py
import coiled
from prefect import Flow
from prefect.executors import DaskExecutor

flow = Flow("test-flow")
executor = DaskExecutor(
    cluster_class=coiled.Cluster,
    cluster_kwargs={
        "software": "user/software_env_name",
        "shutdown_on_close": True,
        "name": "prefect-cluster",
        "scheduler_memory": "4 GiB",
        "worker_memory": "8 GiB",
    },
)
flow.executor = executor
```